# Is there any way to use addClass() to added a class on click in vueJs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I tried this code but not working. Is there any solution? Please help me. Thank you.

```
<div id="app">
  <li class="blah" @click="onClk">
     Divs to be clicked
  </li>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onClk(e) {
        e.target.addClass('red');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or are you not getting the result you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 onClk(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('red');
 }
```

You can check [demo here](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/RwNRaae)

Answer (score 3):

`classList` is not the **Vue.js** way of declarative thinking. Ideally your code would be:

```
<div id="app">
  <li class="blah" @click="onClk" :class="{ red: isActive }">
    Divs to be clicked
  </li>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false
    };
  }

  methods: {
    onClk(e) {
      this.isActive = true;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: When there are multiple li and I want to add active class for specific li which I clicked. This way not work.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun, In that case, you should maintain an array data structure or use some conditionals to determine but doing direct DOM manipulation is not a way to go. You can encounter nasty issues during Virtual DOM re-rendering.

Comment: Tnx for your suggestion.